# What is the inflatable thing inside a tyre called, and which one should I buy for a 42-622 tyre?

Tags: tire, parts, replacement

I was given a 2nd-hand bicycle but it has a faulty front tyre. I don't know a lot about bicycles and would like to get help with choosing the right (inflatable thing inside tyre). The tyre is 42-622 according to the store page of the bicycle. I don't even know what that means.

I also included a photo of my bicycle:

[image]

Comment: By the way: Could it be that your saddle is very low? As a rule of thumb, if you put your heel on the pedal in the 6 o'clock position your leg should be fully extended. It’s *not* required that you can reach the ground with one or both feet while sitting in the saddle.

Comment: Be sure to also check if there's nothing inside the tire (like a thorn or something). Sometimes, thorns get stuck in the tire and is not removed, if you just replace the tube, it might cause another leak. Check also if the front tire is not worn out (cracks or wear indicators), if yes you can replace it with the same you have in the back, they are among the sturdiest tires in the market.

Comment: You may be noticing from the answers that tire sizes are confusing. It's a mish-mash of current standards, outdated standards, and regional dialects. Both of the existing answers are good. But if you're still confused and want to be sure you get the right thing, take it to your local bike shop. Most shops will be happy to take a look at your bike and get you set up with the right parts, including inner tubes. They may even show you how to change it.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. A thorn went through the tube after I rode it in my backyard. I'm 5ft 3" and the bike is quite tall for me. It was adjusted to the lowest point.

Comment: Be aware that you should be able to lower the handlebars quite abit, if it helps your seating position.

Answer (score 9):

It's called an inner tube, and tubes cover a range of sizes that are usually printed on the packaging.

There are 3 things you will need to know

- The valve type (presta/schrader/dunlop)
- The required valve length (so the valve can reach through your rims)
- The size of your tyre (in your case 42-622 which may alternately be written as 700x42c)

Here is a picture of the packaging from a popular tube manufacturer.  You can see in this case that its a 42mm Presta valve and is suitable for tyres ranging from 32-622 to 47-622

[image]

Comment: From the picture it appears that the valve is a Dunlop valve, quite common in Germany and the Netherlands, or a Schrader valve (car type) but not a Presta.

Comment: I agree with @Carel; the valve is too wide given that they're 700C wheels

Comment: Yes, you are correct.
The image hadn't been edited into the the original post when I wrote the answer

Comment: I've made a small edit to make answer more generic and remove reference to suitability for the OP's bike

Comment: It's a Finnish bicycle. The store page didn't give much information about the tube. The model is Elina Tunturi. Thank you for the answers and information. I will have a look in my local shop.

Answer (score 5):

It’s called a tube, they come in different sizes and with different valves.

The 42-622 number tells us that you have 42mm width and 622mm bead seat diameter. (There are two other, less accurate standards, in the American system it would be 28x1.60 inches, in the French it’s 700x40C).

You can pick any tube which fits this size. Usually tubes will support a relatively wide range, for example a 622mm (or 28 inch) tube will often support everything from 28mm width all the way to 48mm width.

There are three different types of valves: Schrader, Presta (also called Sclaverand) and Dunlop. Presta is narrower (allowing for narrower rims) and mostly used on road bikes. Schrader is very common on bikes and used for cars and trucks. Dunlop is common on some city bikes and Dutch bikes. From your photo it seems that you have a Dunlop valve.

Of course you could go for a Dunlop valve again but if your pump supports it I’d go for a Schrader valve. It’s more robust, more widely supported and allows you to pump up your tires at any gas station.

Comment: In America far more people use the 700C designation rather than 28"

Comment: In America, we usually refer to road tires using the 700C designation and mountain bike tires in inches. Don't ask me why. It makes no sense. Also, we call a 622mm bead seat diameter mountain bike tire a 29 inch tire.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and information. I will search for Dunlops or something similar in my local shop.